# Where can i find getArgb function declaration in JavaFX API?

Tags: java, api, javafx

Where can i find getArgb function definition in JavaFX API? (package com.sun.javafx.tk (PlatformImage))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the interface `com.sun.javafx.tk.PlatformImage`, a common interface to all toolkit-specific objects used to store image data for a `javafx.image.Image` object, you can find it on the OpenJFX [repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/3877b0334778/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/tk/PlatformImage.java).

There you can see the `getArgb()` function declaration:

```
/**
 * @param x X coordinate of pixel
 * @param y Y coordinate of pixel
 * @return the non-premultiplied pixel in integer ARGB component ordering.
 */
public int getArgb(int x, int y);
```

Public API `javafx.scene.image.Image` implements a `javafx.scene.image.PixelReader`, an interface that defines methods for retrieving the pixel data from an image, providing all the methods in that interface:

```
new PixelReader() {
    @Override
    public int getArgb(int x, int y) {
        PlatformImage pimg = platformImage.get();
        return pimg.getArgb(x, y);
    }
}
```

The image object has an underlying platform representation:

```
private ObjectPropertyImpl<PlatformImage> platformImage;
```

To find the implementation I've been debugging this:

```
image.getPixelReader().getArgb(0, 0);
```

This leads to `com.sum.prism.Image.getArgb()`:

```
@Override
public int getArgb(int x, int y) {
    return getPixelAccessor().getArgb(x, y);
}
```

and to an inner class `BaseAccesor`:

```
@Override
public int getArgb(int x, int y) {
    return getGetter().getArgb(getBuffer(), getIndex(x, y));
}
```

which finally leads to `com.sun.javafx.image.impl.ByteBgraPre`:

```
@Override
public int getArgb(ByteBuffer buffer, int offset) {
    return PixelUtils.PretoNonPre(getArgbPre(buffer, offset));
}
```

where

```
    @Override
    public int getArgbPre(ByteBuffer buffer, int offset) {
        return (((buffer.get(offset    ) & 0xff)      ) |
                ((buffer.get(offset + 1) & 0xff) <<  8) |
                ((buffer.get(offset + 2) & 0xff) << 16) |
                ((buffer.get(offset + 3)       ) << 24));
    }
```

and `com.sun.javafx.image.PixelUtils`:

```
public static int PretoNonPre(int pre) {
    int a = pre >>> 24;
    if (a == 0xff || a == 0x00) return pre;
    int r = (pre >> 16) & 0xff;
    int g = (pre >>  8) & 0xff;
    int b = (pre      ) & 0xff;
    int halfa = a >> 1;
    r = (r >= a) ? 0xff : (r * 0xff + halfa) / a;
    g = (g >= a) ? 0xff : (g * 0xff + halfa) / a;
    b = (b >= a) ? 0xff : (b * 0xff + halfa) / a;
    return (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
}
```

Comment: I mean function definition.

Comment: It is an interface. It will be implemented in any class that implements or use `PlatformImage`... For instance, it is used in this `com.sun.javafx.tk.ImageLoader` interface and `com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit` abstract class.

Comment: Look in package javafx.scene.image (Class: Image). Look at function getArgb. Look at function return: pimg.getArgb(x, y). Where can i find this getArgb definition?

Comment: Thanks, I had use "Force Step Into" instead of "Step Into" in my Intellij debugger.